# the picture from highcharts in the PDF made by html2canvas is blurry?

Tags: highcharts, html2canvas

[image]

```js
(function() {
 var form = $('#printContent');
 $('#create_pdf').on('click', function() {
  $('body').scrollTop(0);
  createPDF();
 });
 //create pdf
 function createPDF() {
  getCanvas().then(function(canvas) {
   var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   var imgWidth = 210;
   var pageHeight = 295;
   var imgHeight = (canvas.height) * imgWidth / canvas.width;
   var heightLeft = imgHeight;
   var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
   var position = 0;
   doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
   heightLeft -= pageHeight;
   console.log(canvas.height);
   while(heightLeft >= 0) {
    position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
    doc.addPage();
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
//    console.log(position);
   }
   doc.save('file.pdf');
  });
 }

 // create canvas object
 function getCanvas() {
  return html2canvas(form, {
   imageTimeout: 0,
   removeContainer: false
  });
 }
}());
```

I use the `html2canvas` to make PDF, but the charts in the PDF is blurry, is there solution to solve it? the title and the legend are blurry, and the code is below?

Comment: Maybe you may try to use highcharts export server for getting your image and then make your pdf? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: thanks for your answer firstly, but there are other elements in the web like tables which is thought to be printed in the PDF, so the Export module of Highcharts is not suitable. Could you give me other advise? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you set legend to useHTML this solves the problem:

```
legend: {
useHTML: true
}
```